# How to properly declare a JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have included js file in header of the page and after it i have some functions just between `<script></script>` tags. I need transfer an array from header to js file. Because included file with js is above the function i am creating in it empty array `var some_array = []` and after it trying to add the values below with `some_array(inst.temp[0], inst.temp[1]);` and on it receiving:

> ReferenceError: some_array is not defined

```
<script src="templates/js/js.js"></script>// here is var some_array = [];
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){some_array.push(inst.temp[0], inst.temp[1]);})
</script>
```

Comment: Show us how `some_array` is declared.

Comment: @MattBall as written `var some_array = []`

Comment: @NoNameZ So what's that `send_time` variable that I spot in the inline script?

Comment: @MaxArt sorry - just a working variable name. Edited.

Comment: @NoNameZ: Your question is `How to properly declare a JS variable`. Given the context of your post I think your question is more relating to the scope of a variable than how to declare a variable. I have a feeling `some_array` inside `templates/js/js.js` is scoped inside a method and as such has no meaningfull definition when you are trying to use it somehwere else. Posting the relevant content of `js.js` would propably help.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl thanks a lot man, it was in $(document).ready(function())

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a function named `some_array`, not add elements to an array named `some_array`. To add elements to it, try:

```
some_array.push( el1, el2, el3, ..., elN );
```

About your question, the way you are declaring the array is ok, but I wouldn't recomment such practice (declare a variable in one file and use it in another). Your code will be difficult to maintain. You can, however, declare some "namespace" and then insert the var inside it. For example:

**File 1:**

```
var ApplicationNamespace = {};
ApplicationNamespace.someArray = [];
```

**File 2:**

```
ApplicationNamespace.someArray.push( el1, el2, el3, ..., elN );
```